# Nested Task in .net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I was reading about Nested tasks (detached and attached tasks) in .net 4.0. I am able to understand it but not clear in which scenario we can use it. Can someone please give me some real world example where we can make use of nested tasks.

Thanks in advance.